# Add a document to a collection in Marklogic from a web application

Tags: php, marklogic, marklogic-9

We have a web application that is creating and loading a document(s) into a MarkLogic database.  This is functioning fine, but we haven't been able to modify the call to load the document(s) into a specific collection in MarkLogic.

Here is the call:

```
rh_api_call
(
    '<root>
        <ACTION_ID>123-45-6789_action_1234</ACTION_ID>
        <TP_ID>123-45-6789</TP_ID>
        <ACTION_DATE>04112019</ACTION_DATE>
        <ACTION_TYPE>Cancel and Take No Further Action</ACTION_TYPE>
        <ADTR_ID>79552</ADTR_ID>
    </root>',

    array
    (
        'uri' => '/ActionLog/123-45-6789_action_1234.xml'
    ),

    'documents',
    'PUT'
);
```

We want this in a collection called ActionLog. I think the code that needs to be added is something along the lines of:

```
<options>
    <collections>
    <collection>ActionLog</collection>
    </collections>
</options>
```

But I am just not sure about how/where and syntax to add it to the call.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a collection via the `collection` request parameter. So, I think it would be:

```
array
(
    'uri' => '/ActionLog/123-45-6789_action_1234.xml',
    'collection' => 'ActionLog'
),
```

See also: https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/documents

HTH!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed.